Create a Stream using MP3s
I have some code that generates a script using the OpenAI API and then converts the script to an MP3 using a text to audio API. My code runs every five minutes and ensures there is never ending queue of MP3 files.
I then have an HTML/JavaScript player that plays the next MP3 in the queue and then deletes it.
However, I want this to run like a live stream. How do I convert the queue of MP3s to an audio stream. This way if multiple people are listen, they are hearing the exact same thing at the same time.
